# parsing a string in C++ without using Boost

Tags: c++, string

```
const char* mystring;
```

In above variable I will receive value as "ABCD1234" or "abcb1234" I should parse the string and get value 1234 (i.e., after characters). How to do this efficiently in C++?

I always have 4 words before number.

I am not supposed to use Boost.

Comment: I'm sure you've tried something, and it did not work, right?

Comment: Are you able to use C++ string instead of const char* ?

Comment: why without Boost? ie what are the limitations and why can't you get them changed?

Comment: Please make clear whether you will always have 3 letters and 4 digits, and if the letters will always be "ABC" or "abc".

Comment: [`isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) might be a good place to start looking, together with [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: You mean 4 'characters, *not* words.

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without error checking:

```
const char *c = mystring;
while (*c && ('0' > *c || *c > '9')) ++c;
return atoi(c);
```

If you need syntax checking use strtol instead of atoi.

Answer (score 1):

What is the exact pattern of your string?

One thing you might consider doing is using the string method `find_first_not_of()` e.g.

```
string newStr = oldStr.substr( oldStr.find_first_not_of( "ABCDabcd" ) );
```

On the other hand, if you know that you just need what comes after the first 4 characters, it really is a doddle:

```
string newStr = oldStr.substr( 4 );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either of the following to locate the beginning of the digit sequence, as both functions accept multiple characters to be searched for:

- [`strpbrk()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk) to search a `char*`:

  ```
  char* first_digit = strpbrk(mystring, "0123456789");
  if (first_digit)
  {
      /* 'first_digit' now points to the first digit.
         Can be passed to atoi() or just used as a
         substring of 'mystring'. */
  }
  ```
- [`std::string::find_first_of()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of):

  ```
  size_t first_digit_idx = mystring.find_first_of("0123456789");
  if (std::string::npos != first_digit_idx)
  {
      // Use `std::string::substr()` to extract the digits.
  }
  ```